How to check if the object leads to memory leak with autotests?
I have an object, that have internal logic related to events subscription.
I want to write an autotest, that checks if the object can be collected by GC after certain steps.
For example:

public interface IEventPublisher {
    event Action Evt;
}

public class MyClass : IDisposable {
    private IEventPubliser _evtPub;
    public MyClass(IEventPublisher evtPub) {
        _evtPub = evtPub;
    }
    public void Initialize() {
        _evtPub.Evt += EvtHandler();
    }
    private void EvtHandler() {
        // *some logic*
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        _evtPub.Evt -= EvtHandler();
    }
}


[Test]
public void MemoryLeakTest() {
    {
        // Arrange 
        var evtPub = // *mock event publisher with NSubstitute or something*
        var myObj = new MyClass(evtPub);
        
        // Act
        myObj.Initialize();
        // *do some staff maybe*
        myObj.Dispose();
    }
    
    // Assert
    // ASSERT_NO_REFERENCES_TO_myObj
}


So, the main question is what should I put instead of ASSERT_NO_REFERENCES_TO_myObj? And is it at least possible?

Can you not change your event publisher to use some form of weak event handling such that it never is the only thing holding references to otherwise collectible objects and you don't have to re-write this test for every possible subscriber?

@Damien_The_Unbeliever can't clearly get what you mean. Do I have to use some kind of Event bus pattern implementation with weak references to handlers?

This article gives an overview with a WPF slant but the general pattern isn't tied to that one framework.

I would not rely on automated tests to catch memory leaks. It might be useful to diagnose a known problem, but a memory profiler will be much more effective in finding problems in the first place.

I would also try to avoid separate construction and initialization. The posted example code will leak if anyone runs Initialize twice, but only disposes once, and that would not be caught by your test.

I have written a manual test in this answer that does what you want to.
The code makes use of WeakReference and needs to be compiled in Release mode and more importantly if you run on later .NET (Core) 3.0+ you also need to add <TieredCompilation>false</TieredCompilation> to .csproj. More details here.
We try to garbage collect the myObj and if we are successful that means that there are no more references to it (what you test for). In contrast to my other answer that dealt with static events, we still need a way to keep the object that evtPub references from being GC-ed too. One way is via GC.KeepAlive  but maybe you develop a test setup logic that has another reference to the object besides the one by the local variable.
var wr = new WeakReference(myObj);
myObj = null; // prevent local variable from keeping it alive
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();

Assert.False(wr.IsAlive) // if no references to it, it will have been GCed it won't be alive any longer
GC.KeepAlive(evtPub); // not sure if that's your logic but maybe
// alternatively keep evtPub alive in a test setup logic
// that goes beyond the current test method's body

